# CSS Background Img Animation overlapping EVERYTHING. Want to be able to click this and link

Tags: html, css, image, animation, background

So I'm working on my first project - my own personal webpage. I have a background animation that is essentially a looping image that is pulsing. I want to be able to have the user click the "enter" part of the image and it redirect to my homepage, or click anywhere on the entire page for that matter.

My background annimation is overlapping everything and no matter what I try and do it lays over any kind of additional image or text box i try to create that clicks and links to my home page. Anyone have any suggestions?

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/frontpagebackground.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<div class="animation"></div>
<div class="body"></div>



<a class="element" href="website.net/link" title="photo" id="element">photo</a>




</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
 /* hide scroll bar. Y is vertical, x is horizontal*/
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
/*pulsing background img */ 
.animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: pulse 6s infinite;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: black;




}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-image: url('img/home2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;


  }
  25% {
    background-image: url('img/home.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;

  }

  50% {
    background-image: url('img/home2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;

  }
  75% {
    background-image: url('img/home.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;    
    opacity: 1;


  }

  100% {
    background-image: url('img/home2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    opacity: 1;


  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `.animation` should be `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;`, otherwise the other elements will be displayed below it.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to repeat the css attributes that don't change throughout the animation in each and every step of the animation keyframe definition. Just add those to the selector of the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.animation` element

```
.animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: pulse 6s infinite;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: black;
}
```

so all other elements will be displayed on top of it instead of after it. That is, if the order in the markup stays in that way that all other elements come after it. If not, you'll have to set the other elements (or a wrapper element around them) to `position: relative;` and give them a higher `z-index` value than the background element.

Comment: Thank you very much, z-index did the trick. Also, appreciate the heads up on the CSS attributes comment. As you can tell, I'm still a beginner learning my way around. Appreciate the help, +1!

Answer (score -1):

How about a JavaScript onClick listener on the body tag?

You stated you wish to be able to *"click anywhere on the entire page"*. Attaching a bubble up click listener is an easy way to achieve this if you don't mind or are already using Javascript.

```
<body onclick="window.location.href='website.net/link'">
    <div class="animation"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <a class="element" href="website.net/link" title="photo" id="element">photo</a>
</body>
```

Since in comments you indicated a preference for avoiding Javascript and you use html5, you can opt for wrapping the other elements in an `<a>` tag for a similar effect as long as the content fills the space.

However there is one caveat in that nested `<a>` links are not supported in html5.  Therefore, since the button link is the same as the page link you can change the button to a `<button>` tag

```
<a id="link-wrap" href="website.net/link">
    <div class="animation"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>

    <button class="element" title="photo" id="element">photo</button>
</a>
```

And then remove the styling in case you have text

```
#link-wrap {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black
}
```

<strike>By the way I don't see the opening body tag in the snippet.</strike>

Comment: Why should he want to use JavaScript for this instead of a link if it's solvable with pure html+css? Not a good idea to prevent clients without JavaScript or crawlers from entering/indexing the page...

Comment: thanks for pointing out the body tag, I accidently deleted it earlier when messing around. Would like to avoid JavaScript if possible, HTML+CSS ideally.

Comment: @connum I suggested JavaScript because of his wish to click anywhere on the page and bubble up event are easy if you don't mind JavaScript. However given the wish to avoid JavaScript I'll suggest another option too.